# Firestore database query issue

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch all the data from password_entries if the `user_id` is "BED3wChei4NEiDfQP72atUz2NU43"
How can I perform the same.

[image: Firestore screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('password_entries')
  .where('user_id ', isEqualTo: "BED3wChei4NEiDfQP72atUz2NU43")
  .get()
  .then((checkSnapshot) {
    // Document found - do something with it
    print(checkSnapshot.docs[0].data());
  });
```

Comment: I am getting issue in getDocuments().

The method 'getDocuments' isn't defined for the type 'Query'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getDocuments'.

Comment: @tr1via I edited the answer - use the new method

Comment: Nakesh It worked. Thanks :)


`FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('password_entries')
        .where('user_id', isEqualTo: 'BED3wChei4NEiDfQP72atUz2NU43')
        .get()
        .then((value) => print(value.docs[0].data()));`

Comment: @tr1via glad I could help! good week :)